# Which and rowsums to select particular rows, however considering NAs

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is my dummy data. I'd like keep only rows where value is greater or equal 5 in at least 3 (of 5) colums.

```
A <- c(2,4,6,23,8,3)
B <- c(NA,NA,34,5,6,NA)
C <- c(37,21,8, NA, 5,2)
D <- c(12, 67, 12, 4, 11,NA)
E <- c(11, 56, 66, 90, 2,23)
df <- data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)
df
   A  B  C  D  E
1  2 NA 37 12 11
2  4 NA 21 67 56
3  6 34  8 12 66
4 23  5 NA  4 90
5  8  6  5 11  2
6  3 NA  2 NA 23
```

So I decided to use `which` and `rowsums`:

```
df[which(rowSums(df[, c(1:5)] >= 5) >= 3),]
```

what gives me:

```
  A  B C  D  E
3 6 34 8 12 66
5 8  6 5 11  2
```

However I'd like the rows with NAs to be taken into account as well giving the following result:

```
   A  B  C  D  E
1  2 NA 37 12 11
2  4 NA 21 67 56
3  6 34  8 12 66
4 23  5 NA  4 90
5  8  6  5 11  2
```

In other words: row 1 has 1 NA value, but 3 values (of remaining 4) that are >= 5 so criteria are fulfilled.

How can I modify my command to achieve this?

Comment: Simply add `na.rm = TRUE` to `rowSums()`

Comment: Ahh I didn't think it would be so easy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `na.rm=TRUE`.

```
> df[which(rowSums(df[, c(1:5)] >= 5, na.rm=TRUE) >= 3),]
   A  B  C  D  E
1  2 NA 37 12 11
2  4 NA 21 67 56
3  6 34  8 12 66
4 23  5 NA  4 90
5  8  6  5 11  2
```

You can probably do without `which` now, since no longer `NA`s are thrown.

```
> df[rowSums(df[, c(1:5)] >= 5, na.rm=TRUE) >= 3,]
   A  B  C  D  E
1  2 NA 37 12 11
2  4 NA 21 67 56
3  6 34  8 12 66
4 23  5 NA  4 90
5  8  6  5 11  2
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(A = c(2, 4, 6, 23, 8, 3), B = c(NA, NA, 34, 5, 
6, NA), C = c(37, 21, 8, NA, 5, 2), D = c(12, 67, 12, 4, 11, 
NA), E = c(11, 56, 66, 90, 2, 23)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the most straightforward dplyr method would include filtering with `rowsums(x > y, na.rm = TRUE) >=3`.
This would obviate the need for `rowwise`:

```
library(dplyr)

df |> 
    filter(rowSums(pick(everything()) >= 5, na.rm = TRUE) >=3)

   A  B  C  D  E
1  2 NA 37 12 11
2  4 NA 21 67 56
3  6 34  8 12 66
4 23  5 NA  4 90
5  8  6  5 11  2
```

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` equivalent

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union


df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(sum(c_across(everything()) >= 5, na.rm = TRUE) >= 3) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 5 × 5
#>       A     B     C     D     E
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     2    NA    37    12    11
#> 2     4    NA    21    67    56
#> 3     6    34     8    12    66
#> 4    23     5    NA     4    90
#> 5     8     6     5    11     2
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>